# When deploying a Docker container to AWS, do i need to deploy my own reverse proxy as well?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a rails API to handle data and server logic for other client apps. When dockerizing and deploying it to AWS elastic beanstalk (generic docker - single container), it fails. Do i need to deploy multiple containers, to include my own configuration of nginx? or does AWS have a way to handle the reverse proxy for me? Just looking for a little guidance. If I have to handle nginx myself that's fine (and any pointers there would be nice), but I'm actually trying to offload as much setup and configuration as possible onto the services AWS provides and keep a more narrow focus on the code I need to write for the API itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the AWS ALB, so the application load balancer ( https://aws.amazon.com/de/elasticloadbalancing/applicationloadbalancer/ ), which you deploy in the EC section and which does understand you container configuration, thus offers you to target a container / port in your ECB stack. This is the way you would avoid a own nginx container as the load balancer with a configuration, ALB will handle this for you, also with the SSL interception and the promise to be really reliable ( and some limitations )